# Type-safe way to get a string literal of a <const> array with strings

Tags: visual-studio-code, typescript3.0

With the advent of [TypeScript 3.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html), we now have **const contexts**. This can be pretty helpful when you want to specify a list of valid constants for a function's parameter (-s) or similar without having to name every one of them:

```
export const validValues = [
    'Audi',
    'BMW',
] as const;
```

I want to use this syntax to replace the conventional way of defining string literals with "dummy names":

```
export const AUDI = 'Audi';
export const BMW = 'BMW';
```

Using Visual Studio Code, I'm stuck at how I can access these literals from `validValues` using string indices instead of number indices.

Writing `validValues[...` will have Visual Studio Code correctly suggest `validValues[0]` or `validValues[1]` as the type of `validValues` is a two-element array (or tuple). This, however, is not as readable as writing `validValues["Audi"].

Here's an image of Visual Studio Code auto-suggesting the available values.

[image: VS Code auto-suggesting values]

Unfortunately, that does not have VS Code suggesting it because it's wrong semantically (the array is number-indexed) and will thus return `undefined`.

Is this but pipe dream or is there a proper syntax for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a use case where an [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) might suffice, but the keys and values of an enum are generally not the same unless you manually set them that way.

If you want an object where every property at key `K` has value `K`, then you need to build this yourself, as no such built-in data structure exists in JavaScript/TypeScript.

Luckily you can make a function to make an object like this for you:

```
function validValueMaker<T extends string>(...args: T[]) {
    const ret = {} as { [K in T]: K };
    args.forEach(v => ret[v] = v);
    return ret;
}
```

And use it like so:

```
const validValues = validValueMaker("Audi", "BMW");

// IntelliSense prompts these:
validValues.Audi;
validValues.BMW;
```

Does that meet your needs?  Hope this helps; good luck!

Comment: Cheers! This is definitely what I was looking for as it didn't cause my code base to have a meltdown. The line `[K in T]: K` even made me learn about the concept of _mapped types_.
The fact that there's no built-in data structure in the language (yet) almost makes me believe that my case is a rare one or, at the very least, has a low priority.